# kohana 3.2 creating a model for a table with underscore in its name

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-3.2

I am having trouble in creating a model for a table named **product_details**, and after searching sometimes, I found this answer

[Kohana 3.2: Calling model with underscore in name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018396/kohana-3-2-calling-model-with-underscore-in-name)

acoording on the answer, I resorted to the following approach. I created **Model_Product_Details** then i declared `protected $_table_name = 'product_details';` and then saved it in **application/classes/models/product_detail.php**

And the I called it in a controller with this code:

```
$product_details = ORM::factory(product_detail);
```

But damn, it didnt work. the error returned was `ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Model_Product_detail' not found`

I tried renaming the table, model and file name by removing the underscore and it worked. But the thing is the database im using is from legacy system so i cant change its name. I hope could give me help immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing the answer on the link I provided for the third time(I think), referring the approach I've done, I just have to remove the underscore from the file name and the model name only.

So this is the way how to fix it. Lets say you have a table named **product_details**. You have to create **Model_ProductDetail** then in the inside, declare **protected $_table_name = 'product_details';** then save it as **productDetail.php**

Comment: Save it as ProductDetail.php (in the model folder) because of the case sensitivity in linux systems, and use it like ORM::factory('ProductDetail') because of the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you describe is not a missing or misnamend table, but object name.
When underscores are used in the models name, after the Model_ part, every underscore is expected as a folder. For the class with name Model_Product_Details Kohana expects the file details.php to be in the folder models/product/details.php.

```
protected $_table_name = 'product_details';
```

should point to the table on a correct way

Comment: yeah. that's right. take a look on the link in my question. the accepted answer is the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to rename your model to `productDetails`. Kohana searching this model in the `model/product` sub directory. See this here: [link](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/conventions#variables).

"CamelCased class names should be used when it is undesirable to create a new directory level."

Comment: yeah that was discussed clearly here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018396/kohana-3-2-calling-model-with-underscore-in-name and also, i think that is Pascal not camel hehehe.

Comment: :) then camel: ProductDetails.